# PHP - wsdl equivalente para html

Tags: php

necesito realizar pruebas en php que me permita saber si un html está formado de manera correcta. Es basicamente como el equivalente a wsdl para xml. 
Necesito un archivo donde defina que tags (ejemplo div, article,etc) son obligatorios y cuales no y que no tome en cuenta los datos dentro del contenido. Existe algo parecido?

gracias

Comment: no existe una estructura básica mínima de tags HTML que consideren un documento como válido, es decir no hay una reglas general en todo caso si encuentras una opción le tendrás que indicar dichas etiquetas tu

Comment: Un HTML no tiene por qué tener *tags obligatorios*. Si ese es el punto de partida de lo que quieres no tienes otro camino que escribir tu propio código que busque si esos tags existen en tu documento o no. Ese sería tu validador personal para un criterio personal de documento que te has inventando. Si lo que quieres es validar realmente un HTML, entonces tienes clases como **[`DOMDocument`](http://es.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.validate.php)**

Comment: Gracias, era la respuesta que buscaba